# How to constantly listen for output from external program with subprocess without console on Python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, subprocess, tail

I am trying to use a program similar to linux's `tail` but written for Windows 7 OS that outputs every new change from specific `.txt` file via the stdout. Currently I've managed to get it work with:
`subprocess.Popen("readfrom 180101.txt", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` and then extracting every line with `stdout.readline()`

This was the fastest solution I came with long time ago, but now it needs to be working without the console, and with WX.

When I simply try to run it with `PythonW.exe / .pyw` or with `pyinstaller -F -noconsole` the program crashes on `subprocess.Popen`.

Is there any solution for this to work without the need of the console running beside the WX?

Best regards.

Comment: How does it crash? With an error message? In such a case; which?

Comment: @JohanL a message box appears saying "Fatal Error" - "Failed to execute script".